# android: java.io.IOException: stream closed

Tags: android, inputstream, ioexception

I am reading xml data from server and parsing it during which i am getting the following exception.

```
05-07 12:37:31.904: W/System.err(2765): java.io.IOException: stream closed
05-07 12:37:31.907: W/System.err(2765):     at libcore.net.http.AbstractHttpInputStream.checkNotClosed(AbstractHttpInputStream.java:68)
05-07 12:37:31.908: W/System.err(2765):     at  at libcore.net.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:41)
05-07 12:37:31.908: W/System.err(2765):     at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:244)
05-07 12:37:31.908: W/System.err(2765):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.fillBuffer(KXmlParser.java:1496)
05-07 12:37:31.909: W/System.err(2765):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readName(KXmlParser.java:1543)
05-07 12:37:31.909: W/System.err(2765):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.parseStartTag(KXmlParser.java:1045)
05-07 12:37:31.909: W/System.err(2765):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:369)
05-07 12:37:31.909: W/System.err(2765):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:310)
```

my code is

```
**private static InputStream downloadUrl(String urlString) throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");

**///// added after some search about this exception, but it didnt fix the issue fo**r me 

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        //conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        return conn.getInputStream();
    }**


XmlPullParser parser = getParser(in);
parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "response");

            while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
........
}
```

parsing is successful for  first few records in the xml file and then the exception is coming

Comment: an issue with the backend?

Comment: i am able to read first few records of xml . SO there is no issue about connection or permissions .

Comment: backend is the server you are getting the information. Maybe it is him that close the connection

Comment: It may you are reusing the InputStream object any where.. look into code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with XmlPullParser . It has some know issues when downloading big files. I changed my XML parsing to use  DOM . http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/package-summary.html 
and it worked